# Masscan -oG grep output how can i grab just the ip's and save to a file

Tags: file, sorting, awk, grep

here is my output in the test.grep file

```
# Ports Scanned: TCP(1;11032-11032) UDP(0;) SCTP(0;) PROTOCOLS(0;)
Host: 127.0.0.1 () Ports:11032/open/tcp///
Host: 127.0.0.1 () Ports:11032/open/tcp///
Host: 127.0.0.1 () Ports:11032/open/tcp///
Host: 127.0.0.1 () Ports:11032/open/tcp///
Host: 127.0.0.1 () Ports:11032/open/tcp///
Host: 127.0.0.1 () Ports:11032/open/tcp///
Host: 127.0.0.1 () Ports:11032/open/tcp///
Host: 127.0.0.1 () Ports:11032/open/tcp///
Host: 127.0.0.1 () Ports:11032/open/tcp///
Host: 127.0.0.1 () Ports:11032/open/tcp///
Host: 127.0.0.1 () Ports:11032/open/tcp///
Host: 127.0.0.1 () Ports:11032/open/tcp///

# Masscan done at Sun Aug 17 16:46:30 2014
```

and i would like a file with just the ip addresses

```
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
```

can anyone help me do this i am using kali linux

Answer (score 2):

With `grep`:

```
grep -oP '(?<=Host: )\S*' file
grep -oP '(?<=Host: )\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+' file
```

With `awk`:

```
awk '/^Host:/ { print $2 }' file
```

With `sed`:

```
sed -nr 's/^Host: (\S+).*/\1/p' file
sed -nr 's/^Host: ([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+).*/\1/p' file
```

Comment: thanks bro most explained answer used the awk command as it is easy to rember thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -oE '[0-9.]{7,15}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a one liner.

```
awk 'NR>2{ print l} {l=$0}' test.grep | awk '{print $2}'
```

That should do it for.
Explanation:

First awk removes the first and last lines in your file, the next one selectes the 2nd column which is the IP addresses.

Yes, I know I can combine all in one awk statement, but this is simple.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
awk '{ print $2 }'
```